# Dynamic style - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Basivally i have a div ,which i'm putting a dynamic style

```
<div style="position:relative; left: {{et.getNumPadStyle()}}px">
```

My function `getNumPadStyle` will have

```
function getNumPadStyle {
    var num = "25";
    return num;
}
```

This is giving me an error

```
Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: et.getNumPadStyle()
```

And when i inspect the element, the exact number is not reflecting

```
element {
    position:relative;
    left:{{et.getNumPadStyle()}}px
}
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `ng-style` like this:

```
<div ng-style="et.getNumPadStyle()">
```

And in Angular code:

```
    $scope.et = {};
    $scope.et.getNumPadStyle = {
        "padding-left" : "25px"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your angular function has to be in scope and called with $scope.getNumPadStyle()

```
    $scope.getNumPadStyle = function ()
    {
        var num = "25";
        return num;
    }
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/nq19be7h/

Answer (score 2):

There are few errors in your code . Find the code example below

Html :

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <div style="position:relative; left: {{getNumPadStyle()}}px">test</div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.getNumPadStyle= function() {
    var num = "455";
    return num;
}
  };
```

Comment: I am able to get the number in my view.. The problem is binding.. not the scope for sure

Comment: I think the issue is scope for example why do you use 'et' in {{et.getNumPadStyle()}} ? As you can see above @selvassn does not use 'et'...